# How can I perform a post request?

Tags: c#, android, post, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to send a post request from an android game that I created in Unity to a server. When I run this code to send a request from my PC (Unity Editor) it works and I get "OK" as a response.

When I install the app on an Android tablet or phone, the server receives no request from the client phone. Is it possible that the C# code does not run properly on Android? What could be the problem otherwise?

The code clearly runs from the PC and the Android phone/tablet can successfully send a POST request with a REST client. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

public class ServerConnection : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {

            byte[] response =
                client.UploadValues("http://192.168.44.83:12345/keyword", new NameValueCollection()
                                    {
                    { "keyword", "onion" }
                });

            string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);

            Debug.Log (result);
strong text     }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Comment: Just a hunch, but is the application requesting network permission when you install it on the Android device? If not, it might be blocked by Android.In this case you might need to edit the AndroidManifest.xml (see http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/536095/how-to-write-an-androidmanifestxml-combining-diffe.html)